# How do I write this statement using symbols?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Juan is a math major but not a computer science major. (m= "Juan is a math major.", c= "Juan is a computer science major.")

How do I write this is symbolic form using the letters and (and, or, not)?

Comment: Think about how "but" works in connecting the two statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$m$ and not $c$". Can you explain why this is right?

Comment: But means "and". So like this m^~c ?

Comment: You said to use "and, or, not", so I did. But you can also use "$\wedge$" to replace the "and", and use "$\neg$" to replace the "not", and get $m \wedge \neg c$.